# Unable to start process dotnet.exe with multiple projects which are sharing same port

Tags: c#, .net-core, startup

I am transferring platform from MVC 5 to core 2.0, 
project require multiple startups which has custom domains.

My startup project's Url are :

1. https://agent.webz.local:44343/
2. https://superAgent.webz.local:44343/
3. https://client.webz.local:44343/
4. https://general.webz.local:44343/
5. https://agentAPI.webz.local:44343/

if I run project individually, then there is no error but, when I start projects in multiple startup mode, then only 1st one is working, others project returning below error.

> Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web
>   server request failed with status code 500.Unable to start process
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web server request failed with
>   status code 503, Service Unavailable.

*Same domains are working fine with MVC-5.

if I do change the port **44343** to **4434X**, then issue is not coming.

> is there any way to start multiple project with same port.

Comment: No. Only one application can bind to a port at a time, and behavior if the bind is forced is indeterminate.
With multicast sockets more than one application can bind to a port as long as `SO_REUSEADDR` is set in each socket's options. You could accomplish this by writing a "master" process, which accepts and processes all connections, then hands them off to your two applications who need to listen on the same port. This is the approach that Web servers and such take, since many processes need to listen to 80.

Comment: is your comment in relation to .net-core? because right now I have  multiple startup projects with common port is working well on **MVC-5** without any issue. 
***my level of knowledge is not enough to understand this things easily.

Comment: With MVC5 you actually starting a single IIS Express on that port. There is no IIS on .net Core.

Comment: oh yes, i just started read about kestral !

Answer (score 0):

With MVC5 you starting a single IIS Express instance on 44343 port, which handles incoming requests and redirects them to appropriate .net application. On .net Core, each you project is actually a web server (named Kestrel), so you need to bind them on different port. But actualy you can do what you want: Reverse Proxy to the rescue! Lurk more for [Reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and NGinx (for example).